# Safari: jittery shaky text when using css animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my one-pager website I have some containers that has this property

```
.containers   {   
    transition: opacity 1000ms cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94), transform 1600ms cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1);
}

#page {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

where #page is the main wrapper I use in position fixed to prevent browser pull/bounce and make the website feel like an app.

and in my JS I have a function that detects the scroll

```
 $('#page').scroll(function() {
    $(".containers").each(function() {
        $(this).css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + (-$("#page").scrollTop()) + 'px, 0)');
    });
});
```

so whenever the container contains an image the scroll is like butter and silk on both chrome and safari

but when the container contains a paragraph of text. it become jittery

I know the problem can be the fact i have a 1600ms setup that it may create a conflict but why only in Safari (both mobile iphone and desktop)??

Comment: Do you experience said issue from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et0wkgrv/)? Personally, I don't on Safari 14.1 and Safari TP 14.2

Comment: interestingly, in your example i don't notice any jitter. I wonder if because I'm using a font-face then.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions suggested out there, but so far the one that helped me the most is  using `-webkit-transform:` along with `transform:` and now it feels much better especially on mobile